# how to show markers for one series and not for another

Tags: excel, scatter-plot, vba

A part of my current assignment is to, once all data has been calculated successfully (it has), is to plot a scatter showing altitude against time.

This plot requires two series. One for the trajectory start to finish and another to show the apogee.

I have managed to get the chart to show this by defining the scatter as `xlXYScatterSmooth`. I would prefer the full length series to have no markers though.

How do I do this?

```
Dim Chart1 As Chart
Dim xaxis As Range
Dim yaxis As Range
Dim MAXyaxis As Range
Dim Series As Series
Dim SeriesMAX As Series

Set yaxis = DisplayCorrectedAlt
Set xaxis = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(RowCount, 1))
Set MAXyaxis = Cells(1, 9)
Set MAXxaxis = Cells(1, 10)

Set Chart1 = Charts.Add
    With Chart1
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmooth
    End With

Set Series = Chart1.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    With Series
        .Values = yaxis
        .XValues = xaxis
    End With

Set SeriesMAX = Chart1.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    With SeriesMAX
        .Values = MAXyaxis
        .XValues = MAXxaxis

    End With
```

Comment: You can use `xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers`

Comment: try `.MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleNone` inside the `With` block of the series you want no markers on.

Comment: @A.S.H thankyou for the suggestion, unfortunately because there is only one reading for the apogee it doesn't show

Comment: @ScottHoltzman thankyou. I knew it would be a really simple solution but couldn't find it anywhere. 

Am the first of my class to get this far too so couldn't ask any of them.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman: it is a valid answer. You may want to post it to help future visitors

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Was about to do that for just that reason :)

Comment: Thank you @ScottHoltzman :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleNone` against the `DataSeries` object.

Place it inside the `With` block of the desired series, like this:

```
With SeriesMAX
    .Values = MAXyaxis
    .XValues = MAXxaxis
    .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleNone
End With
```